# "Failed to initialize wxWidgets" followed by core dump

Tags: solaris, core-dump, gnuplot

I'm testing some software under Solaris.  The machine runs SunOS 5.11 (Solaris 11.3), and I connect to it over SSH. The software runs its benchmarks and then plots the data points.

The makefile performs the following:

```
$(CC) $(FILES) $(CFLAGS) ../sse/blake2b.c -o blake2b
$(CC) $(FILES) $(CFLAGS) ../sse/blake2s.c -o blake2s
$(CC) $(FILES) $(CFLAGS) md5.c -o md5  -lcrypto -lz
./blake2b > blake2b.data
./blake2s > blake2s.data
./md5 > md5.data
gnuplot do.gplot
```

Here's what it looks like when running it:

```
gnuplot do.gplot
Failed to initialize wxWidgets.
*** Signal 11 - core dumped
```

[do.plot can be found](http://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/blob/master/bench/do.gplot) at GitHub. Trying tricks like `set terminal png` and `set terminal jpg` does not help.

My environment does not set `DISPLAY`, but it does set `TERM`:

```
$ printenv | egrep -i '(term|display)'
TERM=xterm-256color
```

Adding `-v` in an attempt to gather more information results in an `Cannot open load file '-v'`.

Does anyone know whats wrong with `gnuplot`? Or maybe, does anyone know how I can get the program to do something besides core dump (like print verbose information before dying)?

---

`gnuplot` was installed with `pkg install gnuplot`. 13 MB and 1130+ files were downloaded, so I'm guessing all the dependencies are present.

```
$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0
```

Comment: It seems to my memory that gnuplot tries to display the result -- can you ssh with -X so it can display back? Or tell gnuplot to save the output to a file for separate displaying?

Comment: Have you tried either `DISPLAY= gnuplot -e 'set term dumb' do.gplot` or `DISPLAY= gnuplot -e 'set term unknown' do.gplot`? What about `DISPLAY= GNUTERM= gnuplot do.gplot`?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. `ssh ... -X` produces a local `GNUplot-wxt Error`: file is corrupt or not enough memory. It also complains about wrong libpng and library versions. It also seems to make the window hang. The man pages discuss `DISPLAY` and `TERM`, but I don't quite what the interactions are supposed to be. The man pages are not as helpful as I would like. I can't figure out how to make it be verbose, and I can't figure out how to make it save to a file. There's only a handful of options documented.

Comment: It should already be saving to a file (plotcycles.pdf)

Comment: `make TERM="" CFLAGS="..."` and `make DISPLAY="" CFLAGS="..."` both caused core dumps. I found I could avoid it by setting `GNUTERM` to nothing. I.e., `make GNUTERM="" CFLAGS="..."`. Steeldriver - do you want to provide an answer since you were the guy who suggested the twiddling?

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that, although `do.gplot` ultimately writes to a PDF file (plotcycles.pdf) it does so by first plotting to the default output device (probably `wxt`) and then setting the terminal type to `pdfcairo` and issuing a `replot` command.

There appear to be a number of ways to override the default terminal type - either

- on the gnuplot command line e.g.

  ```
  gnuplot -e 'set term dumb' do.gplot
  ```

  (a 'dumb' ASCII terminal - produces a kind of tabular display in the SSH terminal); or

  ```
  gnuplot -e 'set term unknown' do.gplot
  ```

  (which the `set term` command identifies as `Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device`)
- by setting an empty `GNUTERM` environment variable

  ```
  GNUTERM= gnuplot do.gplot
  ```

  which the manual describes as

  > ```
  > GNUTERM
  >   The  name  of  the  terminal type to be used by default. This can be  
  >   overridden by the gnuplotrc or .gnuplot start-up files and, of course, 
  >   by later explicit "set terminal" commands.
  > ```

Since gnuplot is being called via a Makefile in your case, probably the `GNUTERM` variable is the most convenient since it can be passed as a command-line variable to `make`.